# Weird result in setting column values of a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray, numpy-slicing

In the script below, I want to apply a rotation matrix to the first two columns of a `(Nx3)` array.

```
rotate_mat = lambda theta: np.array([[np.cos(theta),-np.sin(theta)],[np.sin(theta),np.cos(theta)]])

rot_mat = rotate_mat(np.deg2rad(90))

basis1 = np.array([[i+1,j+1,k+1] for k in range(3) for j in range(3) for i in range(3)])
basis2 = basis1.copy()
rot = basis2[:,0:2] @ rot_mat

print('rot','\n',rot[:3],'\n')
print('basis2','\n',basis2[:3],'\n')

basis2[:,0:2] = rot
print('basis2 after','\n',basis2[:3])
```

after I ran this script, I obtained this output

```
rot 
 [[ 1. -1.]
 [ 1. -2.]
 [ 1. -3.]] 

basis2 
 [[1 1 1]
 [2 1 1]
 [3 1 1]] 

basis2 after 
 [[ 1  0  1]
 [ 1 -2  1]
 [ 1 -3  1]]
```

as you can see by `basis2[:,0:2] = rot`, the first row of `basis2` is `[1,0,1]`, however, the first row of `rot` is clearly `[1,-1]`, where does this `0` come from?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you take a look at the entries of `rot` you will see that `rot[0,1]` is `-0.9999999999999999`. Furthermore `basis2.dtype == dtype('int32')`. So during the assignment the new entries get converted to `int32` which rounds them towards zero. You can verify that

```
np.int32(rot[0, 1]) == 0
```

and

```
np.int32(rot[0, 1] - 1e-16) == -1
```

This is due to rounding, as `np.cos(np.deg2rad(90)) == 6.123233995736766e-17`, when you'd probably expect it to be exactly 0.

Comment: Odd, though, that a number that is close to `-1`, gets rounded off to `0`. Isn't it?

Comment: @fountainhead, odd things often happen when mixing `float` and `int` datatypes.  If you're rotating, you always want everything's dtype to be float.

Comment: @fountainhead converting from an floating point type to an integer type (typecasting) is always done by using the integer part of the input, in pretty much all common languages. If you want something else you explicitly need to specify that.

Comment: Truncation is a better description than rounding.